# SSIS package fails with error: “Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.”

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I recently updated an SSIS package that had been working fine and now I receive the following error:

`Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.`

The package effectively transferred data from tables in one database to a table in another database on another server. The update I made was to add another column to the transfer. The column is Char(10) in length and it is the same length on both the source and destination server. Before the data is transferred it Char(10) there as well. I've seen people reporting this error in blog posts as well as on Stack, none of what I have read has helped. One solution I read about involved using a data conversion to explicitly change the offending column, this did not help (or I misapplied the fix).

Comment: Have you schema compared the dbs to see if any changes have been made?

Comment: I've double checked the schemas and they all match.

Answer (score 0):

whihc version of SQl Server and SSIS are you usign?

I would say to take a look at the output and imput fields of your components. CHAR always ocupies all it's length (I mean, char(10) will always use 10 bytes) and since you are having a truncation error, it may be a start. try to increase the size of the field or cast as varchar on the query that loads the data (not as a permanet solution, just to try to isolate the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Which connection you are using ADO.Net or OLEDB connection ??

Try deleting the source and destination if there are not much of changes you have to make ..Sometime the metadata cuases this problems. If this doesn't solve your problem post the screen shot of error.

Comment: The source and destination are both OLE DB; I tried deleting and recreating them and now I have the same error but for a different column which is extremely confusing.

Comment: @Gedalya Can you post the screen shot of error. I also asked you to explore the advanced options for both source and destination.